# How do you implement "follow me" using the MyLocationOverlay class?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I made an application which shows the current location of the user using the MyLocationOverlay class. However, when the user changes his location, the marker is not recentered. How do I implement the "follow me" feature?

I am thinking of making the LocationManager to update as frequently as possible and then calling the animateTo method inside the onLocationChanged method but it seems to be a bad solution. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is extend `MyLocationOverlay` as an inner class of my `MapActivity`. Then, I override `onLocationChanged` and use `animateTo` on my `MapController` in that method.

```
@Override
public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        mapController.animateTo(
                new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude()*1e6),
                             (int) (location.getLongitude()*1e6));
    }
    super.onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Comment: Is the frequency to request for location updates on MyLocationOverlay not affected by locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener)? Also how frequent does the location of myLocationOverlay updates? Can I also set it? Or is it final?

Comment: Correct, it is unaffected by other updates as I believe it just uses its own listener. I do not know how frequent the updates are, because the class is closed source. It is not adjustable, so you have to go with whatever the default is, or make your own class

Comment: Thank you, Craigy. I just tried experimenting on your suggestion and yes, it seems that it is not affected by the settings of LocationManager. I will try running my application later on road. :)

Comment: I wasn't able to try your example yesterday. :( My GPS and network is not cooperating with me. They won't show me my location inside the car. I shouldn't have relied on my low end phone. Anyway, I'm still open for other suggestions.